# Prometheus find Memory&CPU usage for each deployments

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

Is there a way to find the memory & cpu consumption of all pods running under deployment?

**Example 1:**

| Name | CPU(cores) | MEMORY(bytes) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a-service-6fddf46985-lkbxn | 100m | 1024Mi |
| a-service-6fddf46985-wftpn | 75m | 1024Mi |
| b-service-xae0016f8d-4z6xx | 50m | 2048Mi |
| b-service-xae0016f8d-2lf4g | 75m | 1024Mi |

I want to see it as in example 2 instead of example 1

**Example 2:**

| Name | CPU(cores) | MEMORY(bytes) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a-service | 175m | 2048Mi |
| b-service | 125m | 3072Mi |

Since the pod scale set values under each deployment are different, the number of pods varies, so I need to find the resources consumed by each service.

Comment: Please [edit] question and add promql query used to get data for your example 1.